# Use of cast in the reshape package.

Tags: r, casting, reshape

I am trying to use the "value=" parameter. It does not do what I want.
The example below replicates the problem in a more simple format. I'm wondering what the "value=" parameter is for.

I have melted a data frame into long format with all my factors and a single numeric variable which takes values 0,1,2,3,4. I then created a second value column with 0,1 to refine the original value column.
Cast works a treat when I try to aggregate as long as it is the ORIGINAL value column.

```
D = data.frame(id = 1:10,
           grp = rep(c("A","B"),5),
           variable = "var",
           value = rnorm(10,0,1),
           value2 = rnorm(10,10,2))

cast(D, grp~., mean)                    #works fine
cast(D, grp~., value = "value2", mean)  #does not work
```

If this is not possible then I will have to manipulate my data.

Comment: By adding a `value2` column, your data are no longer molten. You need to re`melt` and then `subset`. See the "update" section in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11072648/1270695) for what I mean.

Comment: You are quite right.  I did the melt then added the additional value column with 1/0 depending on the original value.  I'll look at the answer and work it through when I get a chance later this evening.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: For your information, `dcast` from `reshape2` seems to work with the data the way you have it. `dcast(D, grp ~ ., mean)` works correctly, as does `dcast(D, grp ~ ., value.var="value2", mean)`.

Comment: Thanks, would you recommend reshape2 over reshape in general?  Is the general functionality pretty much the same otherwise (e.g. melt)

Comment: Most of the functionality seems to be the same, and I think (but can't find sources to verify this) that `reshape2` is seen as the successor to `reshape`, but `reshape` is being kept because it has some different functionality. [The initial announcement](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-pkgs-reshape2-a-reboot-of-the-reshape-package-td2534378.html) of the `reshape2` package mentioned *This version improves speed at the cost of functionality, so I have renamed it to `reshape2` to avoid causing problems for existing users. Based on user feedback I may reintroduce some of these features.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but I think it's because of the following code in `cast`:

```
if (any(names(data) == value)) 
names(data)[names(data) == value] <- "value"
```

Try not using the word "value" in your variable names, for example `names(D)[4:5] = c("one", "two")` and then use `cast(D, grp ~ ., mean, value="one")` and `cast(D, grp ~ ., mean, value="two")` to get the results you're looking for.

### Update

Technically, your data are not fully "molten". See the example below for how you should correctly approach this. It basically involves "melting" your data once again and using `subset`. *(I've changed "value" and "value2" to values that are easier to see what's going on.)*

```
D = data.frame(id = 1:10,
               grp = rep(c("A","B"),5),
               variable = "var",
               value = rep(c(1, 2), 5),
               value2 = rep(c(3, 4), 5))
D2 = melt(D, id.vars=1:2, measure.vars=4:5)
cast(D2, grp ~ ., mean, subset=variable=="value")
#   grp (all)
# 1   A     1
# 2   B     2
cast(D2, grp ~ ., mean, subset=variable=="value2")
#   grp (all)
# 1   A     3
# 2   B     4
```

### Update 2

It seems that any time there is a variable named `value`, that is always the one that `cast` uses, even if you specify another variable for the `value=` argument. The "strategy" section for the help file for `guess_value` (which `cast` makes use of) describes the following two steps:

1. Is value or (all) column present? If so, use that
2. Otherwise, guess that last column is the value column

But, in the few tests I've done, I don't see any way to specify a `value=` argument successfully without renaming the variables or re-melting the data.